# Flash code 'pauses' when in inactive tab?

Tags: browser, flash, browser-tab

Does flash pause its execution somehow if the browser tab in which its residing is inactive?

I developed a multiplayer game using cirrus and when I tried to play it by switching tabs, making a move in each tab, there were some inconsistencies regarding the way the game executed as if the inactive tab pauses the flash execution and then resume once it was active.

The game works perfectly in standalone flash player/debugger.

Comment: which browser are you using? i think some of the newer browsers slow down the frame rate in inactive tabs to minimize CPU load. try using 2 windows instead.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in 10.1 they introduced throttle:

http://saumyaray.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/flashplayer-throttle-solving-a-problem-or-creating-one/

Answer (score 1):

Search your (lib) code for listeners to Event.ACTIVATE and Event.DEACTIVATE.

Those are commonly used to pause a game when it doesn't have focus.